# Runtime.ImportModuleError - Error: Cannot find module 'jmespath'

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, jmespath

How can I fix the below error?

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var jmespath = require('jmespath');
-------------------
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'jmespath'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/aaa.js\n- /var/task/aaa.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/Runtime.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'jmespath'",
```

Comment: check package.json if jmespath is there, then reinstall node modules.

Comment: Which package manager are you using? npm, yarn, other?

Comment: Jmespath was present in package.json, using npm